# Как настроить приём платежей на сайте через qiwi

Tags: qiwi

Уже два дня ищу, пробую и толку ноль.
Пробовал этот класс https://github.com/atnartur/php-qiwi, но выдаёт ошибку: `Ошибка: Прием платежа для данного провайдера запрещен`.
Если посылаю просто get запрос, как показано на сайте qiwi, то выдаёт: `Ошибка: Провайдер не поддерживается`.

Уже не хватает слов, популярный сервис не может дать нормальное и понятное api, нет никаких примеров.
Подскажите кто в курсе, как можно настроить или где посмотреть?

Comment: https://ishop.qiwi.com всё прекрасно описано в личном кабинете.

Comment: Я же написал, я делал всё по описанию и ничего не выходит. Магазин утверждён.

Comment: И я делал по описанию и всё вышло. Без примеров кода никто не поможет.

Comment: Значит ещё раз попробую, может где-то протупил. Физ-лицам же можно тоже принимать платежи через киви?

Comment: Да, можно. Попробуйте без использование класса реализовать переход на страницу оплаты. Если брать документацию с ishop, всё прекрасно работает. Если ничего не получится, то приложите варианты.

Comment: Вычитал в паблике, что может быть с аккаунтом проблема, хотя всё подтверждено, делаю без классов, просто форма и всё как в документации и безрезультатно.